# How to open the Putty terminal within the Windows terminal emulator or the VS Code terminal?

Tags: terminal, putty, terminal-emulator

The terminal emulator within Putty is rather difficult and inconvenient to use.

Comment: If you don't like putty terminal handling, you can run plink in WinTerm and I expect but can't verify in VSCode -- plink does _only_ the SSH communication and not the terminal handling. Also in Win10 up, which are the only versions that run WinTerm, Microsoft supplies a port of OpenSSH in \windows\system32\openssh and ssh.exe also does only SSH.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Plink works. Thanks.